# How to make spring @ManagedOperationParameter work with scala

Tags: java, spring, scala

In my scala code this works fine:

```
import org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.{ManagedOperationParameters, ManagedResource, ManagedOperation, ManagedOperationParameter}
    @Override @ManagedOperation(description = "somedesk")
      def getStatsAsStr: String = "blabla"
```

but as soon as i add `@ManagedOperationParameters` I get `illegal start of simple expression for @ManagedOperationParameter(` although I do import it.

so while in java this compiles fine:

```
@Override @ManagedOperation(description = "some description")
  @ManagedOperationParameters({@ManagedOperationParameter(name = "myname", description = "myname")
})
```

In scala does not compile:

```
import org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.{ManagedOperationParameters, ManagedResource, ManagedOperation, ManagedOperationParameter}
   @Override @ManagedOperation(description = "some description")
      @ManagedOperationParameters(Array(@ManagedOperationParameter(name = "myname", description = "mydesc")) // PRODUCES 'illegal start of simple expression for @ManagedOperationParameter('
      def getStatsAsStr(myname: String): String = "blabla"
```

is there a way for it to work? if i create it as a `.java` with `java` syntax in same project all is fine (which means my depenedncies are fine) i think its something with `scala` syntax i don't get what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inner annotation values have to be constructed with a different syntax.  This should work (whitespace added for clarity, not relevant); if not, try replacing the named parameters with positional.

```
@ManagedOperationParameters(
  Array(
    new ManagedOperationParameter(name="myname", description="mydesc")
  ))
```